# Result source not Working to display result from current site collection

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search

I Have created new result source
[image]

Please see the below image inside New source

[image]

Here you can see it will display result from current site collection only.

In above image http://pc9:9001 is web application and it has site collection like http://pc9:9001/sites/demo

When I go to search enter any keyword then it will display result from another web application also.
[image]

In above image http://pc9 is different web application.
over here the the search result I have created to display result from current web application is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to select "New Source" in Search results webpart properites.
see the picture below to change the query. even you keep that as default source. please do this.

[image]

You just select the "New Source" in highlighted section in Image

[image]

Comment: actually I have do this task without make any changes in search result web part

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Path:{SiteCollection.URL}` for this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Search Center you may need to edit the Search Results web part and "remind it" to use the default result source. I have seen most time just opening the page in edit mode and edit the web part, confirm the result source and click OK and Save and Check in.